# To Count Occurrences of all sub strings in string C#

Tags: c#, string, multithreading, substring

Question: I have a long string and I require to find the count of occurrences of all sub strings present under that string and print a list of all sub strings and their count (if count is > 1)  in decreasing order of count.

Example:

```
String = "abcdabcd"
```

Result:

```
Substrings      Count
abcd            2
abc             2
bcd             2
ab              2
bc              2
cd              2
a               2
b               2
c               2
d               2
```

Problem: My string can be 5000 character long and I am not able to find a efficient way to achieve this.( Efficiency is very important for application)

Is there any algorithm present or by multi threading it is possible. please help.

Comment: Please, have a look at *suffix tree* or/and *suffix array* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: I have tried with suffix tree and suffix array , but there is no fast way possible from suffix tree to find all sub strings.
However if sub string is given as input you can find its count of its occurrences very efficiently through suffix tree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a common string within a list of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509277/find-a-common-string-within-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: @Mekap: I have tried with regex expression . 
# Also tried with finding all sub strings under string through normal loop and finding the sub string occurrences count through suffix tree.
Still efficiency is very poor.

Comment: As per my duplicate comment, you could then simply group by substring and perform a count.  (You can also use PLinq's AsParallel()) to parallelise

Comment: @Clint: I think it is different . The link you shared is the concept of longest common Pattern.(LCP)

Comment: How do you define if something is a substring or not? Why is "abcd" a substring, but "abcdabc" not? Why is "bcda" not a substring?

Comment: And if you take in to consideration all possible substrings: a string of 5000 different characters has about 12.5 million of them

Comment: @derpirscher: yeah that is a challenge.

Comment: I want to know reason for negative ranking on my this question .. I will improve in future that thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using: [Find a common string within a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509277/find-a-common-string-within-a-list-of-strings)

```
void Main()
{
    "abcdabcd".getAllSubstrings()
        .AsParallel()
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Select(g => new {g.Key, count=g.Count()})
        .Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public static class Ext
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> getAllSubstrings(this string word)
    {
        return from charIndex1 in Enumerable.Range(0, word.Length)
           from charIndex2 in Enumerable.Range(0, word.Length - charIndex1 + 1)
           where charIndex2 > 0
           select word.Substring(charIndex1, charIndex2);
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
a 2 
dabc 1 
abcdabc 1 
b 2 
abc 2 
dabcd 1 
bc 2 
bcda 1 
abcd 2 
ab 2 
bcdab 1 
cdabc 1 
abcda 1 
d 2 
bcdabc 1 
dab 1 
bcd 2 
abcdab 1 
c 2 
bcdabcd 1 
abcdabcd 1 
cd 2 
da 1 
cdab 1 
cda 1 
cdabcd 1
```

Comment: It is working good for 1000 character long string but giving Out of memory exception for string length more than 2000.
Error coming in line "select word.Substring(charIndex1, charIndex2);"
Any Suggestions?

Comment: @NancyGarg strings that large are inevitably going to cause OOM errors, that many string ops so quickly creating lots of arrays; my suggestion would be to take the general principle, but use a different structure for working with the string - a string builder / roll something different.

Comment: I have changed 32 bit compiler to 64 bit and it worked. It is very efficient also as compared to my previous approach. Thanks a ton..:)

Comment: No worries @NancyGarg, glad to hear that the 64-bit change fixed your memory issue! If you could mark the answer as accepted that would be great :)

Comment: 1 more help please ,Can you please tell me to save this complete data in to list or dictionary. (i.e to add ToList() and ToDictionary() to linq query or any efficient method)
I want to return any container having strings and its count in most efficient way.

Comment: Sure, just add .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count) after the select.

Comment: hey clint, Can you please help me in optimization of this code further if possible, I am new in c#.             

"
var data = text.getAllSubstrings(minLength, maxLength)

        .AsParallel()

        .GroupBy(x => x)

        .Select(g => new ListInfo()

        {
            ListSubstr = g.Key,
            Substrcount = g.Count(),
            SubstrLength = g.Key.Length
        })
.Where(a => a.Substrcount > 1)

          .OrderByDescending(c => c.SubstrLength)

          .ThenByDescending(c => c.Substrcount)

          .ToList();"

Comment: Hi @NancyGarg if at all possible, could you put this into a more readable medium? I'd suggest perhaps a gist? https://gist.github.com that way we can communicate better there with decent space for code.