# Find a leastCommon string from list

Tags: c#, string

I have a list of strings as:

```
{"\\\\eZREUApp01.EU.abc.com\\eZR_Data\\ALSTOM GIS\\Review_Files",
"\\\\eZREUApp01.EU.abc.com\\eZR_Data\\ALSTOM GIS\\ADP_Processes",
"\\\\EZRSEARCH01.eu.abc.com\\road\\EZR_ALSTOM GIS_7\\",
"\\\\eZREUApp01.EU.abc.com\\eZR_Data\\ALSTOM GIS\\Production_Files\\009",
"\\\\EZRSEARCH01.EU.abc.com\\table\\EZR_Alstom_GIS_7\\",
"\\\\eZREUApp01.EU.abc.com\\eZR_Data\\ALSTOM GIS\\Production_Files"}
```

now i want output in c# as:

```
{"\\\\eZREUApp01.EU.abc.com\\eZR_Data\\ALSTOM GIS"
"\\\\EZRSEARCH01.eu.abc.com\\road\\EZR_ALSTOM GIS_7"
"\\\\EZRSEARCH01.EU.abc.com\\table\\EZR_Alstom_GIS_7 "}
```

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: What is a "leastCommon" string? I have a vague idea of what you're trying to do, but you haven't provided enough information to turn them into actual "rules" or code.

Comment: `"\\\\eZREUApp01.EU.abc.com\\eZR_Data\\ALSTOM GIS"` is not even present in your input list of strings. How can it come in output?

Comment: Can you show your code? It doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: Even if we would understand your requirement, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509277/find-a-common-string-within-a-list-of-strings

Comment: The least common string is the string itself.

Answer (score 2):

Here is example how you can do it.
You have to do the following steps:
1. Split the strings and go over the resulting arrays to get the Minimum number of the child ingoings.
2. Go over the splitted array and take finded in first step number of elements and Concatenate them back.

I'm using `HashSet` so that the result Set will be distinct.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] arr ={"\\\\eZREUApp01.EU.abc.com\\eZR_Data\\ALSTOM GIS\\Review_Files",
                            "\\\\eZREUApp01.EU.abc.com\\eZR_Data\\ALSTOM GIS\\ADP_Processes",
                            "\\\\EZRSEARCH01.eu.abc.com\\road\\EZR_ALSTOM GIS_7\\",
                            "\\\\eZREUApp01.EU.abc.com\\eZR_Data\\ALSTOM GIS\\Production_Files\\009",
                            "\\\\EZRSEARCH01.EU.abc.com\\table\\EZR_Alstom_GIS_7\\",
                            "\\\\eZREUApp01.EU.abc.com\\eZR_Data\\ALSTOM GIS\\Production_Files"};

            string[][] newArr = new string[arr.Length][];

            for (int i = 0; i < newArr.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                newArr[i] = arr[i].Split(new char[] { '\\' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            }

            var min = newArr.Min(x => x.Length); 

            HashSet<string> resultSet = new HashSet<string>();
            foreach(var a in newArr)
            {
                resultSet.Add("\\\\" + a.Take(min).Aggregate((x,y)=>x+"\\"+y));
            }
            foreach(var a in resultSet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your code is amazing! but you have taken 3 as a static value while adding into resultset. We are not sure with the input so we can't take such value.

Comment: @Divya ah forgot to change it back, it must be `min` instead of `3`. I have updated answer

Comment: what would be the solution if we want maximum common with the same input? Using Max function  var max = newArr.Max(x => x.Length); is not working

Comment: @Divya what do you mean saying maximum common?

Comment: suppose i have list as{"abc" , "abc\\def\\xyz" , "abc\\def\\jhh"} right now it is showing output as only "abc". but here my desired output is:[ "abc" , "abc\\def"]

Comment: @Divya can you please strictly determine what do you mean saying "least common" and "maximum common" strings.